# unit test base controller with ILogger

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have a base controller (i didn't create it btw) in my net core api that basically starts with following:

```
public abstract class MyBaseController<T> : ControllerBase where T : MyBaseController<T>
{        
    private ILogger<T> _logger;
    protected ILogger<T> Logger => _logger ?? (_logger = HttpContext?.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<T>>());
}
```

When i am unit testing my other controller that inherits the base controller how do deal with this logger?

currently my unit test class has a constructer with something like

```
_controller = new cartController(_cartService);
```

but then i get stuck.

I will be using xUnit and Moq in the test project.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: The logger should be being injected. Your going to need to change how that base class works.

Comment: Ok but it was done this way to avoid keep writing  :base(logger) for every controller

Comment: Well that's wrong. You base class now has a hard coded static dependency on `HttpContext`. The only other solution is to mock `HttpContext` but it's much simpler to just inject your dependencies correctly. By saving yourself a dozen characters (mostly written by VS) you've just made you unit tests much more complicated.

Comment: can i still use ILogger<T> ? - do i just have something like _logger = logger in the contstructor then?

Comment: Yes you can still use a generic and yes you should add the dependency in the constructor

Comment: thanks Liam for your help

Comment: Liam is correct. This may also be helpful: https://ardalis.com/testing-logging-in-aspnet-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example from [this article](https://christianfindlay.com/2020/07/03/ilogger/) on how to inject an `ILogger` dependency and then verify a call afterward with Moq:

```
public class LogTest
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public const string InformationMessage = "Test message";
    public const string ErrorMessage = "Not implemented {recordId}";

    public LogTest(ILogger<LogTest> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(InformationMessage);
    }
}

_loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(
    LogLevel.Information,
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you should rely on DI in tests as well as in runtime. The following library contains a test logger which you may use in tests: https://www.nuget.org/packages/com.github.akovac35.Logging.Testing/

Usage samples are available here: https://github.com/akovac35/Logging.Samples

Disclaimer: I am the author of the above.

**Basically you would proceed as follows:**

Use NullLogger by default:

```cs
public abstract class MyBaseController<T> : ControllerBase
{        
    private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    
    protected MyBaseController(ILogger<MyBaseController<T>> logger = null)
    {
        if (logger != null) _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Derived classes should inject logger:

```cs
public class MyBaseControllerVariant<T> : MyBaseController<T>
{        
    private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;    

    public MyBaseControllerVariant(ILogger<MyBaseControllerVariant<T>> logger = null, ILogger<MyBaseController<T>> baseLogger = null): base(baseLogger)
    {
        if (logger != null) _logger = logger;
    }

}
```

Now wire up everything:

```cs
using com.github.akovac35.Logging.Testing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Shared.Mocks;
using System;

namespace TestApp
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestLoggingExamples
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            customOnWrite = writeContext => {
                Console.WriteLine(writeContext);
            };

            customOnBeginScope = scopeContext => {
                Console.WriteLine(scopeContext);
            };

            serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(MyBaseControllerVariant<>));

            // Register TestLogger using extension method
            serviceCollection.AddTestLogger(onWrite: customOnWrite, onBeginScope: customOnBeginScope);
        }

        private IServiceCollection serviceCollection;

        private Action<WriteContext> customOnWrite;
        private Action<ScopeContext> customOnBeginScope;

        [Test]
        public void Test_WithLoggingToTestConsole_Works()
        {
            // The service provider should be defined on per-test level or logger writes will accumulate and may result in OOM - clean them with testSink.Clear()
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            var controller = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyBaseControllerVariant<object>>();
            controller.Invoke();

            var testSink = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITestSink>();

            Assert.IsTrue(testSink.Writes.Count > 0);
            Assert.IsTrue(testSink.Scopes.Count > 0);
        }
    }
}
```